# How to implement the scrolling required in a weekly calendar

Tags: iphone, xcode, calendar, scroll

I need to implement a weekly calendar and have not found anything like I did for a day calendar (GCCalendar). So unless someone can point me to something similar I am about to roll my own. I need it to work like the weekly calendar in the iPhone's Calendar app.

I am wondering what the best approach might be to get the scrolling functionality required. When the user drags horizontally the days including their headers (Mon, Tues, etc.) scroll. When the user drags vertically, only the hours scroll up and down. The headers remain stationary and in view.

Is this somehow done in a single ScrollView, or are there 2 scroll views. It seems to me that the easiest approach would be to have 2 scroll views. The header view would only scroll horizontally and somehow I would synch the header and hours view  when scrolling horizontally.

Is there an even better way to do this?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Have you found a solution?